# Simple way to pull taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I am building a module to that uses taxonomy, I would like to use drupal functions as much as possible vs going to the database directly. In addition I am using the Field Module to add additional information to each of the Taxonomy entities.  I would need to be able to dynamically pull back a given set of taxonomies and all fields used. Does anyone have a nice example for doing this. I know there is a function taxonomy_get_tree and there is the field APIs just not sure the best way to implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of pulling all the terms in a vocabulary

```
$vid = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load("catalog")->vid;
//print($vid) . PHP_EOL; prints the vocab ID
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
//print($terms) . PHP_EOL; prints "Array" if a vocab was grabbed
foreach ($terms as $term) {
   print($term->name) . PHP_EOL;
}
```